# Greater than operator question in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found this code that checks the argument to see if it's a prime number and for the most part I got it until I reached the very end.

```
const isPrime = num => {
  for(let i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}
```

what does `return num > 1` do?

Comment: It returns whether `num` is greater than 1.

Comment: It returns the Boolean result of the comparison between `num` and `1` - `true` if the number is greater than `1`, `false` otherwise. I’d recommend brushing up on your [fundamentals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than)

Comment: Well is `1` a prime number? Is zero a prime number? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120/why-is-1-not-a-prime-number

Comment: It's an "operator", learn about all of the Javascript operators [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators)

Comment: If you understand `i < num`, what don't you understand about `num > 1`?

Comment: This code is not really optimized: it tries to divide `num` by each of the numbers preceding it, starting from 2, and returns immediately if this division succeeds (i.e., remainder is zero). But as it should also handle `2` case (which is a prime), and `2 < 2` is false so the loop is not executed even once, it has this check added to the end of the function.

Comment: At the very least, there's not much sense going with `i++` here; if `num` is not divisible by 2, it's also not divisible by 4, 6 etc.

Comment: @raina77ow Most "toy" prime test functions are not optimized. They're used as exercises for looping and demonstrating how the `%` operator works, not algorithm design.

Comment: What is your real question? Do you really not understand what the `>` operator does, or just not why it's used here?

Comment: @Barmar Well, it could've been even slower of course. )

Comment: @raina77ow Who cares? If you want something optimal you use Sieve of Eratosthenes. That's not what this exercise is about.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, it's hard to reason about what's worth attention here without understanding the true purpose of this exercise.

Comment: @raina77ow Simple heuristic: If a total beginner is doing it, it's NOT about the best algorithm, it's about learning the basic operations.

Comment: Jesus Christ y'all I know all the operators, I just never saw it in that form with the return behind it and how it gave back true. that's all.

Answer (score 1):

`num > 1` returns a `Boolean` value depending on value for `num`.

- `true` if `num` is greater than 1
- `false` if `num` is less or equal to 1

```js
let num = 5;

console.log(num > 1); // Logs true

num = 0;

console.log(num > 1); // Logs false

num = 1;

console.log(num > 1); // Logs false
```

As per the function definition the function is checking the input number is prime or not.

**What is a prime number?**

A prime number is a number which is divisible only with 1 and that number.

So here in the function the number is consecutively divided by numbers from 2 to that `number - 1`. If any of the modulus operations return zero, that number is not prime and it returns `false`.

If nothing return false, then the number should be greater than 1

**Please note** 1 is not a prime number.

That is why the last comparison is done. To check whether the number is greater than 1. If the number is greater than 1, the number will be prime.

Because if the number is not divisible by any number from 2 to number - 1, that number should be greater than 1 to be prime number.

Comment: What if num is equal to 1?

Comment: @Barmar false since 1 is not greater than1

Comment: I was pointing out that your bullet items don't mention that case.

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I suspect the OP is really wondering *why* this comparison is used in the `isPrime()` function, not what it means as a JS operation.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my answer definition.

Answer (score 1):

You would think it could just return `true` at the end, as that means the `for` loop did not detect any divisor for `num`, which is what it means for a number to be prime.

The problem is that it would then also return `true` for when `num` is 1. But 1 is not a prime number (by definition), so that would be wrong.

This is the reason why it has `return num > 1`. This is short for:

```
if (num > 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Or:

```
return num > 1 ? true : false;
```

But these are really antipatterns, because they translate a boolean expression in ... the *same* boolean value. You can just *return* the boolean value that the comparison results in, and that is what `return num > 1` does.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 1 is not prime and after the finishing the above loop if compiler reach on this level then number is definitely prime